# Show Mainlayout again from diffetent layout and class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I checked a string variable from web service every 15 min, if returns "0", then new layout open with new class. I want that if returns me different from "0" again main layout shown again. When I press back it shows whitout background music but I want it whole mainactivity and layout automaticly.

```
intent_second= new Intent(this, second.class);

if (str.equals("0")) {
    startActivity(intent_second);
} else {
    //Can I do something here for what I want?
    qst.setText(str);
}
```

this is my code for showing second screen, what Can I do for my request with which class?
Can I do that from mainactivity (calling itself) or how can I send this variable to second class and how can I listen it and start again mainactivity?

Answer (score 0):

```
if flag == 0 then start second activity and on second activity if flag == 1 then call                       finish()    from second activity



           onCreate() {
         intent_second= new Intent(this, second.class);

            if (str.equals("0")) {
            startActivityForResult(intent_second,intent_code);
            } else {
                //Can I do something here for what I want?
                qst.setText(str);
            }
    }

    onActivityResult(Intent intent, code) {

    if(code == intent_code) {
        // update your main layout
               String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
              // here u get you data from second activity "result" is key and it should be used on second activity    
    }
    }
```

Comment: Should I use on create()? It did not work, get error like this `Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements`
 I got same error for on activity result and they want me `protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

 
And if it works how can Update my main layout? What is the code for it?